# Как освободить файл от процесса?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, файлы

Существует некий imageList, в который загружаю файлы следующим образом:

```
// LOAD PHOTO
// get all photos as file and save it in imageListPhoto
int vPhotoSize = 0;
int[] indexDataFacePhoto = new int[400800];
foreach (int i in usersData.readId)
{
    // 1. if you already have a user photo with id equal to i, then =>
    // 2.   => use for listView
    // 3. else download nessesary photo and =>
    // 4.   => use again
    Device.DisableDevice(axFP_CLOCK, m_nMachineNum);
    string pathToPhoto = photoDir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
    // 1.
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToPhoto))
    {
        // 2.
        this.imageListPhoto.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(pathToPhoto));
        continue;
    }
    // 3.
    IntPtr ptrIndexFacePhoto = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(indexDataFacePhoto.Length);
    bool bRet = axFP_CLOCK.GetEnrollPhotoCS(m_nMachineNum, i, ref vPhotoSize, ptrIndexFacePhoto);
    if (bRet)
    {
        byte[] mbytCurEnrollData = new byte[vPhotoSize];
        Marshal.Copy(ptrIndexFacePhoto, mbytCurEnrollData, 0, vPhotoSize);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathToPhoto, mbytCurEnrollData);
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrIndexFacePhoto);
    // 4.
    this.imageListPhoto.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(pathToPhoto));
    Device.EnableDevice(axFP_CLOCK, m_nMachineNum);
}
```

Данный imageList используется в ListViewItem (если нужен код, дайте знать).
После каждого второго вызова формы с данным кодом, любое следующее действие очищает память:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос, как сразу очистить используемую память? Пытался удалять папку с файлами при закрытии формы, но ругается, что файл занят другим процессом. Despose тоже не помог. Строчка `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrIndexFacePhoto);` тоже не сработала.

Comment: Есть методы `Image.FromStream`, `Image.FromHbitmap`. С их помощью можно создавать изображение из памяти. Не обязательно предварительно создавать файл на диске. Вам же они всё равно не нужны, т. к. пишете, что удаляете папку с файлами.

Comment: Уточните, откуда берутся данные для изображений. И в каком формате. Возможно, манипуляции с неуправляемой памятью не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Занятая память != используемая память. Сборщик мусора освободит память тогда, когда посчитает нужным, обычно это происходит не сразу после удаления ресурсов в памяти, а через какое-то время. На объемах в несколько мегабайт вам не стоит об этом беспокоиться вообще. Но код можно оптимизировать, и поправить проблему с занятыми файлами.

Чтобы избежать лишних аллокаций неуправляемой памяти, `AllocHGlobal` можно использовать один раз. Чтобы избежать лишних аллокаций массивов, можно так же создать один буфферный массив за пределами цикла.

```
const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 МБ
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
try
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream(bufferSize);
    Device.DisableDevice(axFP_CLOCK, m_nMachineNum);
    foreach (int i in usersData.readId)
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        string pathToPhoto = Path.Combine(photoDir, $"{i}.jpg");
        try // не используйте File.Exists, он не гарантирует, что через миллисекунду после проверки этот файл останется на месте, то есть проверка будет успешной, а при чтении файла будет исключение, проще сразу обработать его
        {
            ms.SetLength(0);
            using var fs = File.OpenRead(pathToPhoto);
            fs.CopyTo(ms);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) { } // Файл не найден - залогируйте, если надо

        int photoSize = 0; // нет смысла выносить отсюда переменную вовне, если она там не нужна
        if (ms.Position == 0 && axFP_CLOCK.GetEnrollPhotoCS(m_nMachineNum, i, ref photoSize, ptr))
        {
            ms.SetLength(photoSize);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, ms.GetBuffer(), 0, photoSize);
            using var fs = File.Create(pathToPhoto);
            ms.CopyTo(fs);
        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        imageListPhoto.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(ms));
    }
    Device.EnableDevice(axFP_CLOCK, m_nMachineNum);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Теперь должно памяти поменьше кушать.

Ну и определитесь, а стоит ли это все на диск писать?

Comment: Да, код оптимизировался и стал очищать папку, Вам спасибо большое!
Стоило ли хранить на диске? Нет конечно. Я еще почистил эту часть, теперь работает вообще прекрасно)

Answer (score 1):

Когда изображение создаётся напрямую из файла:

```
Image.FromFile(pathToPhoto)
```

оно удерживает хендл на ресурс (файл).
Распространённым способом решения проблемы является следующий:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(pathToPhoto);
this.imageListPhoto.Images.Add((Image)image.Clone());
image.Dispose();
```

Здесь первоначальное изображение, удерживающее хендл, сразу диспозится (можно обернуть в `using`). Таким образом файл освобождается.
А в ImageList добавляется копия изображения. Она с файлом не связана.